# How to view screens that were executed before debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, development-environment

Previously, when I used Visual Basic 6, after setting breakpoints and running up to that point, I could see the screens that had been executed so far by pressing a shortcut key. However, Eclipse projects don't seem to have a feature to view the screens that have been executed so far based on the current breakpoint.

The picture below is an example:
[image]

I want to see a page that shows the screens that have been passed through up to this breakpoint.

In the Debug screen, there is something called Thread, but it seems to only show the currently running page. It doesn't seem to display the pages that have been passed before the breakpoint.

I would appreciate it if you could let me know how to view the screens or related content that were executed before the breakpoint.

Comment: It may help me understand what you want if you [edit] your question and post an example from Visual Basic 6 that demonstrates what you want to achieve in Eclipse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @howlger the OP had Java files in his scribble, any reason for linking a CDT debug view reference for C development?

Comment: @cyberbrain Oops, good point. Thank you for the hint. Correct link: [Java _Debug_ view](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm).

Comment: There are no pages and screens in Java. In Java there are threads (some kind of processes running in parallel). When you pause a thread (e.g. via a breakpoint) you can see the stack frames showing what was called by what (a stack element was called by the element below it). For debugging, it is important to understand that Java is a stack-based VM and to know the correct terms. See also _Help > Help Contents_, e.g. [what the Java _Debug_ view shows](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm).